# `[AVCaptureSession canAddOutput:output]` returns NO intermittently. Can I find out why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am using `canAddOutput:` to determine if I can add a `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to a `AVCaptureSession` and I'm finding that `canAddOutput:` is sometimes returning NO, and mostly returning YES. Is there a way to find out why a NO was returned? Or a way to eliminate the situation that is causing the NO to be returned? Or anything else I can do that will prevent the user from just seeing an intermittent failure?

Some further notes: This happens approximately once in 30 calls. As my app is not launched, it has only been tested on one device: an iPhone 5 running 7.1.2

Comment: Can you show me a little code of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is quote from documentation (discussion of `canAddOutput:`)

```
You cannot add an output that reads from a track of an asset other than the asset used to initialize the receiver.
```

Explanation that will help you (Please check if your code is matching to this guide, if you're doing all right, it should not trigger error, because basically `canAddOuput:` checks the compatibility).

**AVCaptureSession**
Used for the connection between the organizations Device Input and output, similar to the connection of the DShow the filter. If you can connect the input and output, after the start, the data will be read from input to the output.
Several main points:
a) AVCaptureDevice, the definition of equipment, both camera Device.
b) AVCaptureInput
c) AVCaptureOutput
Input and output are not one-to-one, such as the video output while video + audio Input.
Before and after switching the camera:

```
AVCaptureSession * session = <# A capture session #>; 
[session beginConfiguration]; 
[session removeInput: frontFacingCameraDeviceInput]; 
[session addInput: backFacingCameraDeviceInput]; 
[session commitConfiguration];
```

**Add the capture INPUT:**
To add a capture device to a capture session, you use an instance of AVCaptureDeviceInput (a concrete 
subclass of the abstract AVCaptureInput class). The capture device input manages the device's ports.

```
NSError * error = nil; 
AVCaptureDeviceInput * input = 
[AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice: device error: & error]; 
if (input) { 
   // Handle the error appropriately. 
}
```

**Add output, output classification:**

To get output from a capture session, you add one or more outputs. An output is an instance of a concrete 
subclass of AVCaptureOutput;
you use:
*AVCaptureMovieFileOutput* to output to a movie file
*AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* if you want to process frames from the video being captured
*AVCaptureAudioDataOutput* if you want to process the audio data being captured
*AVCaptureStillImageOutput* if you want to capture still images with accompanying metadata
You add outputs to a capture session using addOutput:.
You check whether a capture output is compatible 
with an existing session using `canAddOutput:`.
You can add and remove outputs as you want while the 
session is running.

```
AVCaptureSession * captureSession = <# Get a capture session #>; 
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput * movieInput = <# Create and configure a movie output #>; 
if ([captureSession canAddOutput: movieInput]) { 
   [captureSession addOutput: movieInput]; 
} 
else {
   // Handle the failure. 
}
```

**Save a video file, add the video file output**:

You save movie data to a file using an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput object. (AVCaptureMovieFileOutput 
is a concrete subclass of AVCaptureFileOutput, which defines much of the basic behavior.) You can configure 
various aspects of the movie file output, such as the maximum duration of the recording, or the maximum file 
size. You can also prohibit recording if there is less than a given amount of disk space left.

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput * aMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] 
init]; 
CMTime maxDuration = <# Create a CMTime to represent the maximum duration #>; 
aMovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration; 
aMovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = <# An appropriate minimum given the quality 
of the movie format and the duration #>;
```

Processing preview video frame data, each frame view finder data can be used for subsequent high-level processing, such as face detection, and so on.
An AVCaptureVideoDataOutput object uses delegation to vend video frames. 
You set the delegate using
`setSampleBufferDelegate: queue:`.
In addition to the delegate, you specify a serial queue on which they 
delegate methods are invoked. You must use a serial queue to ensure that frames are delivered to the delegate 
in the proper order.
You should not pass the queue returned by `dispatch_get_current_queue` since there 
is no guarantee as to which thread the current queue is running on. You can use the queue to modify the 
priority given to delivering and processing the video frames.
Data processing for the frame, there must be restrictions on the size (image size) and the processing time limit, if the processing time is too long, the underlying sensor will not send data to the layouter and the callback.

You should set the session output to the lowest practical resolution for your application.
Setting the output 
to a higher resolution than necessary wastes processing cycles and needlessly consumes power. 
You must ensure that your implementation of 
captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer: fromConnection: is able to process a sample buffer within 
the amount of time allotted to a frame. If it takes too long, and you hold onto the video frames, AVFoundation 
will stop delivering frames, not only to your delegate but also other outputs such as a preview layer.

**Deal with the capture process:**

```
AVCaptureStillImageOutput * stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] 
init]; 
NSDictionary * outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, 
AVVideoCodecKey, nil]; 
[StillImageOutput setOutputSettings: outputSettings];
```

Able to support different format also supports directly generate jpg stream.
If you want to capture a JPEG image, you should typically not specify your own compression format. Instead, 
you should let the still image output do the compression for you, since its compression is hardware-accelerated. 
If you need a data representation of the image, you can use jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation: to 
get an NSData object without re-compressing the data, even if you modify the image's metadata.

**Camera preview display:**

You can provide the user with a preview of what's being recorded using an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer 
object. AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is a subclass of CALayer (see Core Animation Programming Guide. You don't need any outputs to show the preview.

```
AVCaptureSession * captureSession = <# Get a capture session #>; 
CALayer * viewLayer = <# Get a layer from the view in which you want to present the 
The preview #>; 
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer * captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer 
alloc] initWithSession: captureSession]; 
[viewLayer addSublayer: captureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

In general, the preview layer behaves like any other CALayer object in the render tree (see Core Animation 
Programming Guide). You can scale the image and perform transformations, rotations and so on just as you 
would any layer. One difference is that you may need to set the layer's orientation property to specify how 
it should rotate images coming from the camera. In addition, on iPhone 4 the preview layer supports mirroring 
(This is the default when previewing the front-facing camera).

Answer (score 2):

Referring from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525132/avcapturesession-stoprunning-method-creates-terrible-hang/19574846#19574846), there might be a possibility that [**this delegate method**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:) may be running in the background, which causes the previous `AVCaptureSession` not disconnected properly sometimes resulting in `canAddOutput:` to be `NO` sometimes.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

The solution might be to use `stopRunning` in the above delegate(Of course after doing necessary actions and condition checks, you need to finish off your previous sessions properly right?).

Adding on to that, It would be better if you provide some code of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's can be one from this 2 cases
1) Session is running
2) You already added output
   You can't add 2 output or 2 input, and also you can't create 2 different sessions

Answer (score 0):

It may be a combination of:

- Calling this method when the camera is busy.
- Not properly removing your previously connected `AVCaptureSession`.

You should try to only add it once (where I guess `canAddOutput:` will always be `YES`) and just pause/resume your session as needed:

```
// Stop session if possible
if (_captureSession.running && !_captureInProgress)
{
    [_captureSession stopRunning];
    NBULogVerbose(@"Capture session: {\n%@} stopped running", _captureSession);
}
```

You can take a look [here](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker/blob/master/Source/Camera/NBUCameraView.m#L182).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you
canAddOutput:
Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given output can be added to the session.

```
- (BOOL)canAddOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output
```

Parameters
output
An output that you want to add to the session.
Return Value
YES if output can be added to the session, otherwise NO.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.7 and later.

Here is the link for apple doc [Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureSession/canAddOutput%3a)